# Inserting data into many-to-many relationship table

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm trying to build a database with multiple tables for a study/research. This is the first time I'm designing database of this magnitude; the database grows by 100-200 records a day, and so far I have the data since 2010. Out of all the data, Generic Sequence Number, Product Name and the Strength of a drug (prescription) is slightly bothering me. This is what I have done so far: 
 Generic Seq number is unique to the strength of drug (product name). So, I have a table that contains id, generic seq no, and strength. Another table is for prod_id and product name. Each Generic seq number may have one or more product name, and each product name may have different generic seq number based on the strength. So, I set it up as many-to-many relationship. I created another table for this relationship that contains rx_id, drug_id, and prod_id. Since many patients may be prescribed for the same drug, the drug_id and prod_id may repeat several times in the rx_table.

My first question is, is this design appropriate? 
How should I insert the data into rx_table? Should I create new record every time for new data even if the drug_id and prod_id already exist in the rx_table, or should I look for the rx_id where the drug_id and prod_id sequence exist and insert the rx_id into the other main table (not shown) which contains other data. 
Or is this question too vague?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your approach is good. Your rx_table is the combination of agent and product name i guess, so it is what you buy as "drug". Basically you have another m:n relationship between your patient table and the rx_table where you manage the prescription of a certain drug (generic seq no/productname) to patients.

Comment: @MartinK. Thank you. That's very helpful. So, just to confirm, keep adding data to the rx_table and create new rx_id even though the prod_id and drug_id combination exist, right? Can you please reply to the message so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is your Generic Sequence Number so i'll just use a real life drug example. From your description i think it's pretty similar to your application. Lets say you have Paracetamol as an agent. Then your Generic Sequence Number table would be something like

```
drug_id | generic_seq_no     | strength
--------+--------------------+----------
1       | Paracetamol-100    | 100
2       | Paracetamol-250    | 250
3       | Paracetamol-500    | 500
```

Your product table would contain the names of the trademarks:

```
prod_id   | prod_name
----------+------------
1         | Tylenol
2         | Captin
3         | Panadol
```

the rx_table contains the combinations of trademark name, agent and strength:

```
rx_id  | drug_id  | prod_id
-------+----------+----------
1      | 1        | 1
2      | 1        | 2
3      | 1        | 3
4      | 2        | 1
5      | 2        | 2
6      | 3        | 2
7      | 3        | 3
```

So e.g. the first row would be Tylenol, containing 100 mg of Paracetamol. Now you have what can be prescribed by a doctor and that's what you already did so far. So as i said your approach is fine.

Now you need (or have?) another table with all your patients

```
patient_id | firstname | lastname
-----------+-----------+-----------
1          | John      | Doe
2          | Jane      | Doe
```

In the end, you must link your trademark/agent/strength combination to the patients. Since one patient may get different drugs and multiple patients may get the same drug you need another many-to-many-relation, let's call it prescription

```
prescription_id | patient_id | rx_id
----------------+------------+------
1               | 1          | 1
2               | 1          | 3
3               | 2          | 4
```

This means John Doe will get Tylenol and Panadol containing 100 mg Paracetamol each. Jane Doe will receive Tylenol with 250 mg Paracetamol. I think the table you will be inserting the most is the prescription table in this model.